# XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration initialization fails

Tags: smack

Here is the source code that I'm using to initialize it in an Android app but it never returns and the app crashes. Has anyone else tried this out? This is smack 4.1 beta.

```
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
            .setCompressionEnabled(false)
            .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required)
            .setRosterLoadedAtLogin(true)
            .setKeystorePath("/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks")
            .setKeystoreType("bks")
            .setSendPresence(false)
            .build();
```

Comment: yup facing the same issue !